# Adding cart price to tracking code on success.phtml

Tags: cart, price, magento-1.6

I need to add some tracking code on success.phtml like this:

```
<img src="https://tracking.tracking.com/lead.php?idClient=12345678&idGroup=12345678&price=I_CANNOT_GET_THIS&idCommande=<?php echo $this->getOrderId(); ?>" alt="" border=“0” />
```

You will see that I need to find:

```
&price=THE PRICE OF THE ENTIRE SUCCESSFUL CART
```

I cannot work out how to get this.

Any help would be very appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

On the success page you can get the last order id with the following snippet.

```
$orderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId();
```

You can then simply load the order from this id.

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
```

And then get the grand total for your conversion.

```
$order->getBaseGrandTotal();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for getGrandTotal. You can try load($this->getOrderId())->getGrandTotal(); ?>